# PowerShell If Statements: IF equals multiple specific Texts

Tags: powershell, if-statement

Good Morning! I'm working on a script and I'm trying to include an IF/Else statement based off a text variable with multiple specific text options and to test for a directory path that will be named after the variable and make the directory if it doesn't exist. So example would be

```
$text = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title,"")

If($text -match "Specific Text1") -and (!(Test-Path $Path\$text))){

new-item -ItemType directory -path $Path\$text

}
ElseIF($text -match "Specific Text2") -and (!(Test-Path $Path\$text))){

new-item -ItemType directory -path $Path\$text

}

ElseIF($text -match "Specific Text3") -and (!(Test-Path $Path\$text))){

new-item -ItemType directory -path $Path\$text

}

ElseIF($text -notmatch "Specific Text1","Specific Text2","Specific Text3"){
write-host "invalid input"
}
```

Im providing users a list of the valid inputs, that can be entered into the text box. When I try running the script I'm still getting errors saying the folder already exists and it's not ignoring it like it should be.

A side question is there a cleaner way to write this?

**Edit**

Below is the answer that worked perfect for me. Thank you everyone for your responses!

```
$text = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title,"")
$AcceptableText = @("Specific Text1","Specific Text2","Specific Text3")
If ($text -in $AcceptableText)
{
    If (!(Test-Path $Path\$text)) 
    {
        new-item -ItemType directory -path $Path\$text
    }
}
Else
{
    write-host "invalid input"
}
```

Comment: "When I try running the script I'm still getting errors saying the folder already exists" - please post the error and the actual sample input with which it fails. Your post also only contains one "side question" - what is your primary question? :)

Comment: The last `ElseIF($text -notmatch ...` is redundant and can be simplified to just `Else` as you already exclude the conditions in the prior `If` and `ElsieIf` statements.

Comment: The problem with the original code is parentheses management. The `if` and `elseif` statements are prematurely closing because they should in fact be `if ((` and `elseif ((`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to create the directories if your user chooses one of 3 text phrases and the directory doesn't already exist, and complain to your user if they choose something other than the 3 text phrases.  I would treat each of those cases separately:

```
$text = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title,"")
$AcceptableText = @("Specific Text1","Specific Text2","Specific Text3")
If ($text -in $AcceptableText)
{
    If (!(Test-Path $Path\$text)) 
    {
        new-item -ItemType directory -path $Path\$text
    }
}
Else
{
    write-host "invalid input"
}
```

Or you could test for the existence of the directory first like this:

```
$text = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title,"")
$AcceptableText = @("Specific Text1","Specific Text2","Specific Text3")
If (!(Test-Path $Path\$text))
{
    If (($text -in $AcceptableText)) 
    {
        new-item -ItemType directory -path $Path\$text
    }
    Else
    {
        write-host "invalid input"
    }
}
```

### Edit

Or, if you want to be tricky and avoid the Test-Path (as suggested by @tommymaynard), you can use the following code (and even eliminate the Try|Catch wrappers if you don't want error checking)

```
$text = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title,"")
$AcceptableText = @("Specific Text1","Specific Text2","Specific Text3")
If (($text -in $AcceptableText)) 
{
    try { mkdir -path $Path\$text -ErrorAction Stop } #Change to -ErrorAction Ignore if you remove Try|Catch
    catch [System.IO.IOException] { } #Do nothing if directory exists
    catch { Write-Error $_ }        
}
Else
{
    write-host "invalid input"
}
```

### Edit

Also worth noting that there are many ways to [Use PowerShell to Create Folders](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/learn-four-ways-to-use-powershell-to-create-folders/).

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly! Thank you! and it's way cleaner than I had it before

Comment: The solution I wrote earlier, which I didn't bother including once I refreshed the page, had a check against the directory's existence first. Did you happen to test which of these two options was faster? I can't deny that I'm curious. I suppose that checking against an array in memory is probably going to be faster than checking for a directory within the operating system.

Comment: @tommymaynard I edited my answer to include a solution which does not check the existence before hand, but encases the `mkdir` within a Try|Catch [System.IO.IOException]|Catch block.

Comment: @tommymaynard Just re-read your comment and realized I never answered your question.  No, I did not check which one was faster, just wrote them out for reference.  I would expect the `Test-Path` to be the instruction that takes the longest...having to go to disk and all...so I would expect the solution which tests for validity of the input text first to be faster, as it only does the `Test-Path` on valid inputs.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can :) Note that in the switch statement, default is being executed when all the other cases are not matched. Please test it and let me know.

```
$text = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title,"")
if (!(Test-Path $Path\$text))
{
    switch ($text)
    {
        "Specific Text1"
        {
            new-item -ItemType directory -path $Path\$text
        }
        "Specific Text2"
        {
            new-item -ItemType directory -path $Path\$text
        }
        "Specific Text3"
        {
            new-item -ItemType directory -path $Path\$text
        }
        default
        {
            write-host "invalid input"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I considered a switch as well, but since the command run each time was the same, I felt the nested IF to be cleaner.

Comment: then you probably want to work with arrays, like in the other answer from Matthew

Comment: What Matthew said. I'd recommend the OP use an array, as well. There's too much duplicated code in this example. The New-Item command only needs to be included in the code once. It's often a good test of your solutions: If you're writing the same command more than once, then you better have a really solid reason as to why. =)

Answer (score 4):

Start by worrying about the input validation *separately* from the `Test-Path` call:

```
$validValues = 'Specific text 1','Specific text 2','Specific text 3'
$text = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title,"")

if($validValues -notcontains $text) {
    Write-Host "Invalid output"
}
elseif(!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $path\$text)) {
    Write-Host "Item exists"
}
else {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -LiteralPath $Path\$text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A select-string version:

```
if ('text' | select-string text,text2,text3) { 'yes' } 

yes
```